# Converting Gif to mp4 where the mp4 is longer than animated gif?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to tell ffmpg to convert animated gif to mp4 that is longer than run time of the animated gif ? Les say the gif is 4 sec long setup to be repeated as animated gifs tend to be, but I need 10 sec mp4 out of it. How would I do it in ffmpg. My current line for converting looks like this:

ffmpeg -i $i.gif -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 4 -b:v 300K -vf scale=320:-1 -movflags +faststart $i.mp4; done

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, suppresses looping of GIFs but you can disable that behaviour.

```
ffmpeg -ignore_loop 0 -i $i.gif
   -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 4 -b:v 300K -vf scale=320:-1 -t 10
   -movflags +faststart $i.mp4
```

You'll have to manually specify the total time using `-t`.

Comment: Thanks a ton ! just to correct, I needed -ignore_loop 0 so it keeps looping until the video is done -ignore_loop 1 will stop before it loop...